# Node.js function in squares brackets syntax [function] or [function: isBuffer]

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I am sorry if it's such a noob question. But I have been inspecting the `global` var in `node.js`  and am stumbled by the syntax.
It's obviously a JSON object, but it looks like:

```
reallyExit: [Function: reallyExit],
binding: [Function: binding],
exit: [Function]
```

Hence, my concrete questions are:
 1. If they have a function object, why do they put it in square brackets?
 2. Why do they put a key-value pair in brackets? `[Function: reallyExit]`
 3. What is then the difference in key definitions: `[Function: reallyExit]` vs. `[Function]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> It's obviously a JSON object

No, it isn't. [Acceptable types in JSON](http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-core.html#anchor8) does *not* include functions. Since those variables are functions, what you're seeing is the [`toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/toString) for Function, not Object.

> Why do they put a key-value pair in brackets?

If you're using `console.log` within the node command-line, then, instead of a normal `toString`, you're probably seeing the output of [`util.inspect`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_object_options). Instead of the normal `toString`, `util.inspect` gives "...a string representation of object, which is useful for debugging".

In other words, node's `console.log` will use the brackets as a terse way to represent various objects, functions, arrays, etc.

> What is then the difference in key definitions: [Function: reallyExit] vs. [Function]

Difference is the former is a [function declaration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function) and the latter is a [function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function#Named_function_expression). For example:

```
> function y () {}
> var x = function () {};
> y;
[Function: y]
> x;
[Function]
```

Comment: How does this answer my question I am failing to comprehend? Official documentation says `global` is an {object}. https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html

Comment: @AVX `global` is an object, but that does not make it JSON. `binding` and `exit` (which are essentially fields of `global`) are _functions_, which is why you're seeing them printed out differently. I've updated my answer as to why you get this format.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is a great explanation!

Answer (score 1):

It's a format that Javascript Objects take when handling `toString`. `[Function: something]` is not a key-value pair. Here, I think you get the object's prototype (`Function`) and it's declared name (when it was not an anonymous function originally).

Javascript objects are not JSON-s. JSON is a notation for exchanging data. It is derived from Javascript, but is an independent format nowadays.

Comment: So [] have a 3rd meaning in this sense other than an array or indexing of an object?

Comment: You can't use `[]` like that in code. It's simply a format used to represent objects in the console, in logs, etc. It has absolutely nothing to do with neither Javascript as a syntax nor JSON.